# Passing an object from Angular to a filter

Tags: angularjs, node.js, parameter-passing

I'm quite new with angular and node.js, I have a route that passes an object to Angular (this is `routes.js` ) :

```
var index = function(req, res) {
    var idCompanyAndUser = req.user;
    res.render('index', {
        idCompanyAndUser: idCompanyAndUser
    });
};
```

then, in `index.js`, I have:

```
<%= idCompanyAndUser.company_shortname %>  //this works correctly

<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filterByCompany /*this is what I want to do*/ :idCompanyAndUser">
```

and in app.js I have:

```
  app.controller('RemoteStreamsController', ['session', '$location', '$http', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', '$interval', function (session, $location, $http, $scope, $rootScope, $window, $interval) {
        //stuff here
        }]);

    app.filter('filterStreamsByCompanyLogged', function() {

        return function(items /*I want to pass it here*/ , idCompanyAndUser) { 
    //other stuff here
}
    };
```

But this doesn't work. How can I pass this object to the filter?

Answer (score 0):

you can send multiple params to your filter.Here is usage in template.

```
{{ variable | myFilter:arg1:arg2...  }}
```

or in filter you need to pass those args like that args can be a object or a array or any other parameter

```
angular.module('MyModule').controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $filter){
    $filter('MyFilter')(arg1, arg2, ...);
})
```

for more details please refer this tutorial [enter link description here](http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/how-to-use-angularjs-filters.html)

Comment: thanks, but filter works, the problem is that passing parameters in this way doesn't. All I need is to access to `idCompanyAnduser` in `app.js` . Is this possible? If I try to pass it with

`<tr ng-repeat="user in users | filterByCompany:idCompanyAndUser">`

it says that idCompanyAndUser is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the json data by using simple {{ x in xx filter:name }} and **name** should be come through json data in your controller or if you would like to use filter as method app.filter then watch it :

app.filter('Filtername', $obj){
 ------------ do your filter code
return $obj;
}

and use it as {{ x in xx filter:Filtername }}

Answer (score 0):

An alternative idea is to use JSON parameterization. As is, the built in OrderBy Angular filter can only take a list of **strings** -- but if we make a custom filter and serialize the params as a JSON string, we can parse those params in the filter and apply them. We can even apply built-in filters programmatically this way, too.

---

Here's a JSFiddle example with a short users list. You can sort and reverse sort the columns by first or last name or age:

https://jsfiddle.net/zt1h6q1s/2/

**filterApp JS**

```
// the main (app) module
var filterApp = angular.module("filterApp", []);

angular.module("filterApp")
    .controller("UsersController", 
    function UsersController($scope) {

        $scope.sort_by = {
          'column': 'last_name', 'reverse': false
        };

      $scope.SortBy = angular.toJson($scope.sort_by);

      $scope.changeSort = function(sortColumn) {
        if (sortColumn) {
          // New Column or old and reverse?
          if ($scope.sort_by.column === sortColumn) {
            $scope.sort_by.reverse = !$scope.sort_by.reverse;
          } else {
            $scope.sort_by.column = sortColumn;
            $scope.sort_by.reverse = false;
          }

          $scope.SortBy = angular.toJson($scope.sort_by);
        }
      }

      $scope.users = [
        {
          "first_name": "LtCmdr",
          "last_name": "Data",
          "age": 33
        },
        {
          "first_name": "Miles",
          "last_name": "Obrien",
          "age": 13
        },
        {
          "first_name": "Captain",
          "last_name": "Picard",
          "age": 29
        }
      ];

    });


  angular.module("filterApp")
    .filter("usersFilter", function($filter) {
        return function(usersList, paramsJsonStr) {

        // PARSE the Json String
        var params = angular.fromJson(paramsJsonStr);
                // var column = params.column;
        // var reverse = params.reverse;

        // Programatically apply the built-in "OrderBy"
        // filter as before, using the parsed parameters
        return $filter('orderBy')(usersList, params.column, params.reverse);

      }
    });
```

**Table HTML page**

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="filterApp" ng-controller="UsersController">

  <p>
    Sort By &nbsp; = &nbsp; {{sort_by}}
  </p>

  <hr>

  <table class="users-list">
    <thead>
      <th ng-click="changeSort('first_name')">
        First Name &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </th>
      <th ng-click="changeSort('last_name')">
        Last Name &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </th>
      <th ng-click="changeSort('age')">
          Age &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- <tr ng-repeat="u in users | orderBy:sort_by.column:sort_by.reverse"> -->
      <tr ng-repeat="u in users | usersFilter:SortBy">
        <td>{{ u.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.age }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

It's a hack-a-round, but it works if you really want to use an object for a filter. Hope that helps!